Virtual Environment Points to Incorrect Python Path After Moving Project
I am working on a Python project in Windows using a virtual environment (venv) created with python -m venv. When I try to activate the environment using venv\Scripts\activate, the environment activates, but running pip or python results in an error pointing to an incorrect path from a different project:
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"e:\projects\manufacturing\venv\scripts\python.exe" "E:\Projects\mer\venv\Scripts\pip.exe" -V': The system cannot find the file specified.


It seems that the virtual environment is still referencing the Python executable and paths from the old project (e:\projects\manufacturing) instead of the current one (e:\projects\mer).

What I've Tried:

Checked the venv\Scripts folder and found all activation scripts (activate, activate.bat, Activate.ps1), but none of them explicitly reference the incorrect path.
Opened the pyvenv.cfg file in the virtual environment root, but it looks fine (no reference to the old path).
I know I can recreate venv. but just why?

What I Need:

Where might this incorrect path be hardcoded in the virtual
environment?

How can I fix it without recreating the virtual
environment?

Could this be related to the pip configuration or
cached paths, and how do I resolve it?


Thanks in advance.

It is surprising that nothing in activate contains a hardcoded path. It usually does. We can't really tell without those script. But every environment I have, create by venv, contains a hard coded path in activate
